# How to write to a Spark SQL table from a Panda data frame using PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

The pandas.DataFrame.to_sql() method will let you write out to a database the result of your data frame. This works fine in the context of a standard RDBMS. How to use this with Spark SQL though, using PySpark ?
I need a connection parameter for this method - what can that be ?

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SparkSQL has nothing to do with the to_sql() which connects to a SQL engine.
If *sc* is your SparkContext

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom','Major','Pete'], 'Age':[23,45,30]})

from pyspark import SQLContext
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

spark_df = sqlc.createDataFrame(df)
```