# How to use ODBC connection for pyspark.pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-sql-database

In my following `python` code I successfully can connect to `MS Azure SQL Db` using ODBC connection, and can load data into an Azure SQL table using pandas' dataframe method [to_sql(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). But when I use `pyspark.pandas` instead, the `to_sql(...)` method fails stating no such method supported. I know pandas API on Spark has reached about 97% coverage. But I was wondering if there is alternate method of achieving the same while still using ODBC.

**Question**: In the following code sample, how can we use `ODBC` connection for pyspark.pandas for connecting to Azure SQL db and load a dataframe into a SQL table?

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
#import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import datetime

data_df = ps.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/myDataFile.csv', low_memory=False, quotechar='"', header='infer')

.......

data_df.to_sql(name='CustomerOrderTable', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={'OrderID' : sq.VARCHAR(10), 
   'Name' : sq.VARCHAR(50),
   'OrderDate' : sq.DATETIME()})
```

Ref: [Pandas API on Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/languages/pandas-spark) and [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html)

**UPDATE**: The data file is about 6.5GB with 150 columns and 15 million records. Therefore, the pandas cannot handle it, and as expected, it gives OOM (out of memory) error.

Comment: It looks like `pyspark.pandas` only supports `JDBC`, [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/from_to_dbms.html#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20write%20it%20back%20to%20the%20stocks%20table%20as%20below%3A) Would it be possible to do `to_pandas()`, or is the file size too large?

Comment: @BeRT2me Good question - that prompted me to add an **UPDATE** section.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you were appending the data to the table, so this work around came to mind.

Break the `pyspark.pandas` into chunks, and then export each chunk to pandas, and from there append the chunk.

```
n = len(data_df)//20 # Break it into 20 chunks
list_dfs = np.array_split(data_df, n) # [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]

for df in list_dfs:
    df = df.to_pandas()
    df.to_sql()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official `pyspark.pandas` documentation by Apache Spark, there is no such method available for this module which can load the pandas DataFrame to SQL Table.

Please see all provided methods [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/pandas_pyspark.html#pandas).

As an alternative approach, there are some similar asks mentioned in these SO threads. This might be helpful.

[How to write to a Spark SQL table from a Panda data frame using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263157/how-to-write-to-a-spark-sql-table-from-a-panda-data-frame-using-pyspark)

[How can I convert a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame back to a sql table in databricks notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048777/how-can-i-convert-a-pyspark-sql-dataframe-dataframe-back-to-a-sql-table-in-datab)